# Unable to change model parameter in the classic_control environments in OpenAI gym

Tags: openai-gym

I am working with the CartPole-v1 environment and I am trying to change some of the model parameters (such as `force_mag`) in order to test the robustness of my algorithms w.r.t model variations. I am trying to do so with the following code:

```
env = gym.make('myCartPole-v1) 
env.force_mag = -10.0 # nominal is +10.0
```

but I do not see any change in the model behavior, while testing it with my learnt policy (which should fail/worsen, but it does not). Nothing happens when changing other parameters (e.g.
masscart, length...). Am I missing something? What is the best way to produce local changes to the models?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by creating an instance of the environment and by calling `env.unwrapped`. The code in the example should look like: `env = gym.make('myCartPole-v1).unwrapped`